# Is there any way to restrict the selection of the check box in list view according to the dynamic value?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am having a list view (say 10 items with check boxes), I want to restrict the user to select `i` items (i.e.,i=1 or 2 or 3 or 4...).

Say if `i=3`, the user can only select 3 check boxes from the list, he will be not able to select the 4th check box. And if we scroll the list view the items will get reset to the old values as we know that can be handle by using Boolean state in the model class.

How can I restrict the user to select particular items from the list view?

Here is my listener:

```
final int i=3;
    holder.cb_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            model.setChecked(isChecked);

            if (isChecked) {
                GlobalCounter++;
            } else {
                GlobalCounter--;
            }


            if (GlobalCounter>i) {
                buttonView.setChecked(false);
                model.setChecked(false);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Here's a suggestion. Maintain a counter. Each time the user checks a box increase it, unchecks it then decrease it. Check the counter with the value. If it is greater than the permitted don't allow him to check.

Comment: I have edited my question,please check it i have tried it.need a good approach.

Comment: I suggest you to move the checking of the counter above the setChecked statement.

Comment: do you want to control the checked checkboxes inside the adapter or in the activity/fragment that holds the listview?

Comment: @UmaKanth...yes thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @CptEric...ill keep that in adapter class

Comment: how about radio group? It will allow you select only one

Comment: yes for single select u can use the state of the particular item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer, for those who want to add particular selections in the list view.

Inside Adapter class on onClickListener:

```
holder.cb_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            model.setChecked(isChecked);
            if (isChecked) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count--;
            }
            Log.d("ttt", "c="+count+" mc="+max_count);
            if (count>max_count) {
                buttonView.setChecked(false);
                model.setChecked(false);
                count=max_count;//count will not exceed the limit. 
                Toast.makeText(context, "You can only select "+max_count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
```

Initialize the `int count=0,max_count=0;` global to the adapter class, while setting the adapter pass the max_selection count to the adapter class.

Here it is for the value 3:

```
final ComboAdapter adapter=new ComboAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_items, arr_list,3);
    lv_combo.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using

**boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();**

if(!checked){

//perform action here if needed

}

but in your case you have to manage no of checked boxes 3 information

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
final int i=3;
holder.cb_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (GlobalCounter>i) {
            buttonView.setChecked(false);
            return;
        }

        model.setChecked(isChecked);
        if (isChecked) {
            GlobalCounter++;
        } else {
           GlobalCounter--;
        }
    }
});
```